# Which data structure is well suited for concurrently inserting and conditionally removing items in a wait free manner?

Tags: data-structures, concurrency, language-agnostic, network-programming

I am currently storing IP addresses and ports for outgoing TCP and UDP packets on my network. I monitor the network and wait for responses to those packets.

Every packet that comes in to the network is first checked to see if it was solicited or unsolicited, by searching the list of IP addresses and ports for past outbound packets.

Currently, I use a dynamic array that is locked and then searched for each packet that arrives on the network. This has been fine until we have upgraded to 100 mbps services. At peak times we have a lot of contention in the search function as indicated by our profiler.

Looking at a lot of different algorithms, I have not found much that is suitable for this particular type of use. Most that I have looked at detail atomic insert and atomic access, which is pretty simple overall.

I was thinking that it might be an improvement to first copy the array, search it, remove the item if it is found, and make a compare-and-swap of the two array references/pointers. If the CAS succeeds, it's good to go. If not, then do it over again until it does.

However, this is intensely memory heavy and I imagine it may degrade performance. We have a lot of memory to use, but I believe that during peak times, there will be a lot of CAS failures.

I will be working on this implementation to do some profiling, but I am curious as to if anyone else has ever come up with a solution to this problem and would be willing to share. Examples in any language are good, although I am working in C and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´d rather use a dictionary data structure to solve your problem. You may use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)
or create your own and use a lock-free linked list (there are a lot of references in the web) to handle collisions.

Comment: How does your solution handle the fact that one IP address can be associated with numerous ports? If you use `ConcurrentDictionary<IPAddress, List<int>>` you end up having a problem accessing the list and still need to lock it; this happens for any data structure in the `Value` property of each `KeyValuePair<TK, TV>` in the dictionary.

Comment: At some point you will have to lock, either the entire dictionary, each list, each node or each pointer (using CAS). It´ll depend on your application and how much time you want to expend coding it (.net doesn´t have a lock-free list). Lock-free DS are hard to code, and wait-free DS even worst. Besides, in much cases, they have a poor performance.

As I said before I recomend you a lock-free list or simply a lock based list. I think it´ll be an improvement over your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a single array containing all past IP addresses and ports, and multiple processes accessing it. That would explain the "contention on search": not a contention between two searches, but a contention for any search while the whole array is being written by one of the other processes.

I'd imagine something like a B-tree would ease your problems. Search time drops from O(N) to O(log N), and writes will only change (and hence cause contention on) a small part of the data. There may well be B-tree variant data structures and algorithms specifically for IP addresses and ports already out there; this seems somewhat analogous to a store and forward switch. A paper that looks close is http://www.rhsmith.umd.edu/faculty/cdell/papers/ieee96.pdf